# Como Separar esta cadena: [{"status":"0"},{"status":"1"}]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quiero que me traiga los dos datos pero por separado pero no me trae nada.

```
      try {
           JSONArray json = new JSONArray (response);
               JSONObject objeto = json.getJSONObject(0);
               String status = objeto.getString("status:");
               Log.e( "onResponse: ",status.toString());

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: acá estas hablando de Java, no veo para que usar la etiqueta de JS

Comment: ¿No trae nada `response`? o es al instanciar `objeto` que no obtienes nada? ¿Sale algún error en el log? Si es así, edita la pregunta y lo incluyes.

Answer (score 0):

Tal ves si recorres todos los elementos:

```html
        array.forEach(item -> {
            System.out.println(item.toString());
        });
```

Donde array es tu JSONArray (json) en tu código.
La salida tendría que ser:

Key:Value
['status':'0']

Answer (score 0):

ya pude asi me separa la cadena

```
                  try {

                        JSONArray json = new JSONArray (response);

                        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
                            String status = json.getString(i);
                            Log.e( "onResponse: ",status.toString());
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```